# What are the requirements to submit a new module to vue-storefront?

Tags: vue-storefront

I cannot find a module publishing guidelines for VueStoreFront. How can we announce/publish a new module for the platform?

We have a module and would like it to be seen as "official" (and maybe advertised by VueStorefront staff, I don't know), hopefully making it a popular feature.

Are there any guidelines to do so? Have someone released such a module for the VueStorefront platform or have experience in releasing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now just ship the RAW code from module template and install it as a git submodule in src directory. In release 1.8 we are planning to add full transpilation for npm packages with 'vsf' prefix which means it Will be possible to ship it as npm package

Please be patient since we currently working on marketplace that will make publishing proces extremely easy:)